# Is position_dodge2() working for python with plotnine?

Tags: python, ggplot2, geom-bar, python-ggplot, plotnine

I'm using ggplot in python with plotnine, I have this piece of code:

```
my_plot_availability = (ggplot(df)         
+ aes(x='time_elapsed',y='mean',fill='policy')    
+ geom_bar(position=position_dodge(),stat = "identity", color = "black",size = 0.5)
+ geom_errorbar(aes(ymin='mean-error', ymax='mean+error'), width=.2,position=position_dodge(.9))
+ facet_wrap('mobility')
+ scale_fill_manual(["darkgray", "gray"])
+ labs(x = "Time elpased [s]") 
+ labs(y = "Mean content availability")
+ theme(element_text(family="Times",size=12))
)
```

that plots this figure:

[image: plot]

And I want to have the same size bars, even if in some cases like case 0 there is only one bar. I know I should do it with:

```
position=position_dodge2(preserve='single')
```

But I'm getting the following error in python:

```
NameError: name 'position_dodge2' is not defined
```

Do you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upgrade your version of plotnine to v0.6.0.

Comment: I did that, now I get: ValueError: Unknown distribution 'logistic'

Comment: I checked here https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/issues/71 but it was closed with no solution.

Comment: @BlueMountain, your environments and packages are probably mixed up and plotnine is probably using an old version of scipy.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use it like this:

```
import plotnine as p9

position=p9.position_dodge2(preserve='single')
```